# How should I represent a n-dimensional two-dimension vector?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, representation-theory

I am having to write an article about frecuency over some function. On this article, I've been advised to represent the data as a 2-dimensional vector and after that, I would need to say that all this data is part of a vector $S$. For example and to clarify: If the element $a_n$ (which is not a number) appears with a rate of $25\%$, then it should be represented as $(a_n,0.25)$.

A more visual representation of what I would like to represent is:

$((a_1,0.33),(a_2,0.33),(a_3,0.33))$

The thing I don't understand is how could I express this types of data over the common rules of set. $\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{N}^2$,... And I need the representation to use it to represent the form of a function over it like it would be $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

What I've though is maybe, as for n dimensional vectors we use $\mathbb{R}^n$, I though of using $(M\times\mathbb{R})^n$, but since I've never seen anything like that, I doubt it would be correct to use.

Comment: Use $2\times n$-matrices. They form a vector space of dimension $2n$, so you could map it to $\mathbb{R}^ {2n}$.

Comment: The problem is that some of the data aren't numbers itself, so I can't make a matrix of reals, neither of the other set, since it doesn't have reals on it. Should I create another set joining reals and my set?

Comment: Certainly $0.33$ is a real number. So the question is, what is $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$? You wrote "number $a_n$ appears with a rate of ...", so I had assumed it is also a real number.

Comment: I want it to be some element, like it could be a character for example, and you are right, i corrected the post, thanks

Comment: Then you should not write "number $a_n$".

Comment: At this point, we are no longer really in the realm of math then, as what you are looking for is really just a way of representing the data, with no internal stucture. Usually this will be called a $2\times n$ array (which is really just the same as a matrix, except we don't have any of the matrix operations)

Comment: How to represent something depends on what you want to be able to do with it. Unless we know that, it will be difficult to help.